# git flow clarification - is rebase better than merge? Please explain

Tags: git

When working with git, before starting work on a feature or an issue, I would do following steps

```
git checkout master // make sure you are on local master

git fetch origin // get latest commits from remote

git merge origin/master // merge latest commits from remote into local master

git checkout -b new-branch // create new branch from up-to-date remote master
```

However, I am reading Atlassian tutorial for feature-branch workflow, and they suggest doing following

```
git checkout master

git fetch origin

git reset --hard origin/master

git checkout -b new-branch
```

Obviously, except step 3, we follow identical steps.  But as new git user, I am confused with step 3 even after I read explanation of what it does.

**What is different btw my and their step 3?
Which and why is better?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you show is from Atlassian's [Git Feature Branch Workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow) 
Under normal circumstances, **after a fetch**, there is not difference between `git merge origin/master` and `git reset --hard origin/master`.

**However**, `reset --hard` is destructive and I would avoid executing it routinely. `merge` is something you could undo if you execute it by accident in a wrong branch, or at a different moment.

---

## Simpler way

BTW, you can just

```
git checkout master
git pull 
git checkout -b feature_branch
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into [this post](https://medium.com/@dmytrechko/differences-between-git-merge-and-git-rebase-dc471d84c72d)

> Briefly:
>    - **git merge** apply all unique commits from branch A into branch B in one
>      commit with final result
>    - **git merge** doesn’t rewrite commit
>      history, just adds one new commit
>    - **git rebase** gets all unique commits from both branches and applies them one by one
>    - **git rebase** rewrites commit history but doesn’t create extra commit for merging

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit wrong!

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

is not rebase, it's [hard reset](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset); see also [Reset Demystified](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Reset-Demystified).

In your case it means "remove all local changes in the current branch and move the branch pointer to `origin/master`". The advantage of it is the command completely synchronizes your local branch with remote; the disadvantage is that it removes your local commits and uncommitted changes if there were any.